# Can a jailbreak survive installation of a new IPSW?

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I have a phenomenon here on an iPad 1. It was running 4.3.2 and a jailbreak was applied to it.
Later it has been updated to 4.3.5 which it is still running.

I wrote a little test app to see if I can detect a jailbroken device. The tests I use are:

- Use [NSFileManager fileExists] to check if /private/var/lib/apt exists
- Use [NSFileManager fileExists] to check if /Applications/Cydia.app exists

The idea is: on a device that is not jailbroken, access will fail in both cases as the app cannot reach out of its sandbox. If either test returns YES, I assume a jailbreak. I tested this on a couple of unbroken devices and neither can be accessed. I also tested on a jailbroken iPhone 3GS and both can be accessed.

The I tried the iPad 1 with 4.3.5 and there is no Cydia installed, so the 2nd check obviously failed but the first one passed! fileExists returns YES for "/private/var/lib/apt"! How is that possible? Can anybody explain?

Comment: What is the programming related question?

Comment: You see the checks I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't completely explain this but I've come across similar results.

I used to have a jailbroken iPod on iOS 3 and updated it to iOS 4, after jailbreaking again my settings in Cydia were still present.
When installing a new firmware iTunes still shows ~500Mb of other data, so I'm assuming not everything gets overwritten / deleted during the update.

Comment: Apparently, the jailbreak survives if you update a device. That explains it.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say *the jailbreak survives*.  I think some *artifacts* of jailbreaking are not removed from the device.  But, the core aspects of the jailbreak, such as being able to run code not signed with Apple certificates, is lost, when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, let me explain why and how this works:

**The iPhone/any iOS device has 2 separate partitions:**

*/dev/disk0s1 mounted at / (around 1GB), the root partition:*

It contains the OS (/System, /Applications, /usr, /sbin, /dev, /Library) and is by default mounted read-only.

*/dev/disk0s2 mounted at /private/var (rest of the space), the user partition:*

It contains all user data (in /private/var/mobile/) like:
Applications, Preferences

Nowadays, all jailbreak tools move all Applications, etc. from the root partition into /private/var/stash to save space on the Root partition. These are then symlinked back from their original location.

When running an iOS update, the user partition is left mostly untouched, only the root filesystem is restored. Only if you run a full restore, everything is deleted. iOS will then recreate the /private/var filesystem on the fly.

**But please refrain from using this kind of code**, since not all of the people who have jailbroken their iOS devices are pirating apps, and you putting such code into your app will only tempt script kiddies to crack it again.